# Using a Variable in OPENROWSET Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, openrowset

I'm having trouble with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI',
    'DRIVER={SQL Server};',
    'EXEC dbo.sProc1 @ID = ' + @id 
 )
```

Gives an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

As suggested by Scott , you cannot use expressions in `OPENROWSET`.Try creating a dynamic sql to pass the parameters

```
Declare @ID int
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @ID=1
Set @sql='SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET(
               ''SQLNCLI'',
               ''DRIVER={SQL Server};'',
               ''EXEC dbo.usp_SO @ID =' + convert(varchar(10),@ID) + ''')'

-- Print @sql
 Exec(@sql)
```

Answer (score 17):

OPENROWSET requires string literals, not expressions.  It's complaining about the plus sign, because it doesn't expect anything more than a string literal and you followed the string literal with an operator.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx which states:

> 'query'
>
> Is a string constant sent to and executed by the provider...

Comment: Thanks Scott, I think the error msg I was getting gave me that idea.

Answer (score 4):

```
Declare @Route VARCHAR(200)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @Route='C:\OCRevisiones.xlsx;'
Set @sql='SELECT * INTO FFFF
FROM OPENROWSET(
               ''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
               ''Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;Database=' + @Route + ''',
               ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'')'

 Print @sql
 --Exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post only-code answer, but include an explanation. Especially for a question like this, where the question is "why is this not working?" and not "what else would work?"

Comment: While generally I agree that posts should have some explanation, there wasn't a lot of explaining needed as the question was answered in Dec 2012.
I found this response useful in that it shows the arguments values for connecting to an Excel file (the database argument) and sheet$ as an alternative to a SQL Server database and table.

Answer (score 3):

If you need parameters you can also use `sp_executesql`:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE
@p_path varchar(200)='D:\Sample\test.xml',  
@v_xmlfile xml,
@v_sql nvarchar(1000)

SET @v_sql=N'select @v_xmlfile= CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) FROM 
OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@p_path+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;'

EXEC sp_executesql @v_sql,N'@v_xmlfile xml output',@v_xmlfile output;

SELECT @v_xmlfile

END
```

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth.. 
The reason we use openrowset rather than a straight linked server query is that the processing for a linked server query happens on the local server. (Slow and often brings most of the table back)

Yes we can do the string concatination as above.

A different option where you have ease of syntax and the power of parameters.

Create a stored proc on the remote box, that proc has all the parameters you need.
Call the stored proc from with a standard linked server query (same perf or better than the above soultion and significantly easier to code with.

e.g. linkedservername.database.dbo.myproc 123,'abc','someparam',getdate()

Just an option....

Comment: this answer might be better if it explained how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Char(39)` instead of `'`

```
set @lcSql= 'SELECT production_pbook_uq,variety_uq,color_uq,grade_uq,diff_qty
            FROM OPENROWSET("SQLNCLI",
            "Server=.;Trusted_Connection=yes;",
            "EXEC serversql.dbo.sp_flower_production_varieties_consolidated @lcproduction_pbook_uq='+char(39)+@lcWo_uq+char(39)+', @lcproduct_piso_uq ='+char(39)+@lcpiso_uq+char(39)+'")'
            +'where diff_qty>0'

print @lcSql
```