# Using Local Variables for comparing data in the Excel being read in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to read data from an Excel using the Following statement which is working absolutely fine

```
Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\input.xls','select MyColum from [Sheet1$]')
```

the XLS inpout.xls has two columns ID and NAME. Now I want the above statement to return only ONE value/row where ID = x and assign the returned value to a local variable as shown below -

```
DECLARE @dbValue varchar(20)
DECLARE @I int

SET @I = 1

Select @dbValue = (Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\input.xls','select MyColum from [Sheet1$] where [ID]=@I'))
```

this returns an error

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "No value given for one or more required parameters.".
>   Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
>   Cannot execute the query "select MyColum from [Sheet1$] where [ID]=@I" against OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Please suggest.

Comment: Something like `... where [ID]='+Convert(varchar,@I)` would be the Dynamic SQL way, but someone will come along and warn about SQL injection vulns :)  However, you may need to create the query string in advance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831472/using-a-variable-in-openrowset-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work. But your question is confusing, since your query on the Excel file selects MyColumn, but you say that file has columns ID and NAME.

```
DECLARE @dbValue varchar(20)
DECLARE @I int

SET @I = 1

Select @dbValue = NAME FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=d:\input.xls','select ID from [Sheet1$]') as T
WHERE ID=@I;
```