# Component to copy files from one directory to another using TF

Tags: ssis

In SSIS, how to copy files ( Loop through Folder) from one directory to another using Task Factory Pragmatic Works?

Comment: you dont need any component from TF, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626457/ssis-openrowset-query-flat-file/39646773#39646773

Comment: I have to use a Task Factory Component. It's not an option

Comment: is not an option? is your Visual Studio broken? TF are **additional** components, they don't replace the already existing components in Visual Studio. There are so many other reasons why your statement makes no sense to me, you may want to explain it, maybe others may help.

Comment: By Company policy, I have to use secure FTP to copy files over

Comment: SSIS supports SFTP out of the box

Comment: I thought SSIS only has FTP Task Component. Could you explain little more on how SSIS suports SFTP out of the Box

Comment: I was mistaken. SFTP is not.