# Unable to upload image to SQL Server using express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, sql-server, image, express

I am using node.js, express, express-fileupload and SQL Server. I am trying to upload images of signatures into the SQL Server database table. When I use the code below, I get an error

> Cannot bulk load because the file "\tmp\tmp-1-1686629760086" could not be opened

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Insert_Signatures_SP
    (@SignatureUri NVARCHAR(1000),
     @UserID INT)
AS
    DELETE FROM Signatures
    WHERE UserID_FK = @UserID;

    DECLARE @err INT
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO Signatures (UserID_FK, [Signature])

    SELECT @UserID, BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET
    (
        Bulk '''+ @SignatureUri +''', SINGLE_BLOB
    ) AS [Signature]';

    EXEC @err = sp_executesql @sql, N'@UserID INT', @UserID; 
    RETURN(@err);
GO
```

My EJS file:

```
    <form action="/admin-signatures-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" class="hiddenField" id="userid" name="userid" value="<%= user.UserID %>" required>
      <button id="<%= user.UserID %>" class="btn1 catbtn" >Upload Signature</button>
      <div>
        <input type="file" name="myImage">
      </div>
    </form>
```

My server.js file:

```
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles : true,
    tempFileDir : '/tmp/'
}));

app.post("/admin-signatures-upload", async function (req, res) {
    try {

        if (!req.files) {
            return res.status(400).send("No files were uploaded.");
        }

        console.log('Path = ' + file.tempFilePath);

        await pool.connect();

        const resultUserCategories = await pool.request()
            .input('SignatureUri', file.tempFilePath)
            .input('UserID', req.body.id)
            .execute(`Insert_Signatures_SP`);

        await pool.close();

        res.redirect('/admin-signatures');

    } catch (error) {
    }
})
```

Comment: Seems very similar to this question [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454428). Is your express app running on a Windows server or a Linux server, because the path seperators are different on the two platforms (and Windows requires a drive prefix like `C:\\` if you need to access temp files on a different drive than where the web app is hosted).

Comment: Is the express app hosted on the exact same machine as the SQL Server? If not you'd need to use a file share that's accessible to both processes, S3 storage, Azure blob storage, etc..

Comment: It is running on a Windows server and the SQL Server and express app are hosted on the same machine.