# OPENROWSET won't accept a variable?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2008 R2

This doesn't work:

```
IF @exists = 1 
    SELECT
        @pic = pImage.BulkColumn
    FROM
        OPENROWSET(BULK @fn, SINGLE_BLOB) AS pImage
ELSE
    SET @pic = NULL
```

unless I replace @fn (an NVARCHAR) with a hard coded string like **N'C:\path\to\some.jpg'**. But there must be a way to use a variable there, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Dynamic sql, something like in this answer: [Using a Variable in OPENROWSET Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831472/using-a-variable-in-openrowset-query)

On your case it would be something like:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
IF @exists = 1 
SET @sql = 'SELECT pImage.BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @fn + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS pImage'

sp_execute @sql
--Here you would need to add something to retreive @pic (I didn't add it since I don't know what @pic is. You can guide you with this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx
ELSE 
SET @pic = NULL
```