# Read JSON into Local SQL Variable

Tags: sql, json, azure-sql-database

I want to read a large number of JSON files (about 1000) from Azure Blob Storage and insert them into a Azure SQL Database SQL table, along the lines of [this tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/one-sql-cheat-code-for-blazing-fast-json-queries-d0cb6160d380) but by reading the JSON from a file rather than inline. To be clear: I want each file to be read as a string that becomes a single NVARCHAR(max) entry in the table. This seems like it should be straightforward, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Below is my code, which yields an error "Incorrect syntax near '('" at the line I have commented. Each JSON file is simply a dictionary, all with the same keys, along the lines of

{"D": "0.980287579", "B": "0.679793971", "C": "0.217004033", "A": "0.675980258"}

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.testJSON', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.testJSON
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.testJSON (
    rowID smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    jsonData nvarchar(max)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.testJSON
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Check for JSON] CHECK (ISJSON(jsonData)=1)
GO

DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @file AS VARCHAR(4000)

WHILE @i < 1000
    BEGIN
        SET @file = 'JSONfile' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.json'
        -- Line below doesn't work
        SELECT @json = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK(@file), SINGLE_CLOB) AS j
        -- Line above doesn't work
        INSERT INTO dbo.testJSON (rowID, jsonData) VALUES (@i, @json)
        set @i = @i + 1
    END
GO
```

Thanks for y'all's help!

Comment: Where is your file? It's kinda important. If this is in SQL Azure then you can use `CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE` to refer to blob storage. Then you can use `BULK INSERT` to insert files from blob storage and write them to a table.

Comment: Do not write "doesn't work". Actually explain what happens. Monitor flies away? Plants grow out of your keyboard?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid updated. Yeah, it's Azure, but it's not as simple as a `BULK INSERT` (I don't think). I want just a single column which contains JSON strings. I can't even find the right syntax to pass to `OPENROWSET`, but I have specified the error message...

Comment: Thanks for adding detail to your question. Blob storage is certainly not accessed vai C drive. I've inserted multiline files from blob into SQL Azure in the past. The only difference is your files have only one line. I think I've explained this on here before - I'll see if I can find it

Comment: Here's a basic guide on inserting files into SQL Azure from blob storage https://argonsys.com/learn-microsoft-cloud/library/loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Thanks. I did a poor job making the question clear, but have made a few edits and hopefully it is now clearer. My solution is below--it refers to another question, but the answers in that question involve some more complex OPENROWSET parameter knowledge that my answer doesn't require so hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will refer readers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831472/using-a-variable-in-openrowset-query) question, which phrases it better than me. You have to use dynamic SQL to insert a variable in an OPENROWSET. The working code is:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.testJSON', N'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.testJSON
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.testJSON (
    rowID smallint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    jsonData nvarchar(max)
)
GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.testJSON
    ADD CONSTRAINT [Check for JSON] CHECK (ISJSON(jsonData)=1)
GO


DECLARE @i INT = 1
DECLARE @numObservations INT = 1000
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @file VARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(4000)

WHILE @i <= @numObservations
    BEGIN
        SET @file = 'testJSON' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5)) + '.json'
        SET @sql = N'INSERT INTO dbo.testJSON (rowID, jsonData)
        SELECT ' + CAST(@i AS VARCHAR(5)) + ', * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @file + ''', DATA_SOURCE = ''AzureBlobStorage'', SINGLE_CLOB) as x'
        EXEC(@sql)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
GO
```

Comment: I think the important part here is how you set up the `AzureBlobStorage` data source - there is a lot of set up behind this and there is detinitely no C drive involved.

Comment: That's a different process and is a fairly easy setup ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the C: drive thing was just because I was changing names of things for anonymity, so ignore it (I removed it in an earlier edit).