# Using variable in openrowset, result in syntax error

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to declare connection as a variable and use it in a query:

```
DECLARE @connStr VARCHAR(MAX) = 'server=xxxxx'
DECLARE @table VARCHAR(MAX) = 'xxxxx'

BEGIN
DELETE FROM @table;
INSERT @table
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
    'SQLNCLI', 
    @connStr, 
    'SELECT TOP 10 * from xxxx ORDER BY xxxx DESC'
);
END;
```

And it results in syntax error.

What's wrong with @connStr? I'm using SQLServer 2012

Comment: `OPENROWSET` does not support variables, period. Only string literals. Doing anything dynamic with `OPENROWSET` requires dynamic SQL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So I need to use `exec`?

Comment: If you really need the connection string to be variable, yes. And certainly if `@Table` is also intended to be a variable holding a table name (which will not work either). In that case, you are much, much better off doing this client-side, as T-SQL does *not* like dynamic result sets, and having multiple levels of escaping is no picnic either.

Comment: If `@table` *is* supposed to represent a dynamic table's name, why is is a `varchar(MAX)`? An object name can be at most 128 characters long, not 2Billion...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a Variable in OPENROWSET Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831472/using-a-variable-in-openrowset-query)